# Do I need to sanitize the input? PDO and mysql escape

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, database-administration

```
//create user
$create_user = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users (email, passwordhash)
                       VALUES (:email, :passwordhash)');
```

Do I still need to use some kind of mysql_escape_string if there is the prepare statement as above?

Comment: No you don't need to sanitize.

Comment: No need to sanitize the data

Comment: Bind variables are automatically escaped; so doing it manually yourself as well will double-escape that will cause you problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to use `mysql_escape_string` in PDO prepare statements that bind the variables. PDO will take care of that, untill you pass the values directly in the preapare function.